# Interaction with Libreoffice Impress: how to identify relevant slide when using "Go to page or object"?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, slideshow, libreoffice-impress

In Libreoffice Impress, I am using the `Interaction` command to create button/links between slides. When clicking on `Interaction` then `Go to page or object`, this open a dialog with

- Slide 1
- Slide 2,
- etc

It is quite challenging ans cumbersome to find which is slide 1, 2, etc... Is there a way to identify which is slide with title "ABC" on the dialog? Maybe by using placeholdeer, slide title?

[image]

Comment: The Slide Pane in Normal View, and the Slide Sorter View, do not show what you need? https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/openofficeorg-many-views-impress

Comment: those are unfortunately frozen when opening the dialog!?